# Why I'm getting error when creating a new sale order line in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm trying to create a new sale order line from a custom module but I'm getting this error:

`convert amount from unknown company`

This is the code I'm using:

```
order_line.sudo().create([{'product_id': itemId,
'product_uom_qty': quantity,
'order_id': orderId}])
```

PD: The order has company_id and currency_id filled.

Comment: sudo is deprecated used with_user(1)

Comment: @jo541 that was the issue, thanks a lot!!